# Missing glyphicons in Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

i downloaded glyphicons from [here](https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons), but can't load some of these icons in Boostrap 2.3.2. I tried to load phone and chat icons, but buttons are empty without icons. In browser console are no errors. How can i show these icons in Bootstrap 2.3.2 please?

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-chat"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-phone"></i></a>
```

Comment: Did you include the stylesheet (properly)?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, bootstrap.icon-large.css file is included

Comment: Bootstrap 2 works with an image for the icons .. did you include that image? in the right path? referenced by the css?

Comment: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i> works for me

Comment: @Danko Yes i included the image

Comment: @michael I don't know why, but this solution doesn't work for me, Macsupport's works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the css and the png in the correct paths, it looks like the proper use is:

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-chat"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-phone"></i></a>
```