# Can't display any Glyph from Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Based on this code I cannot retrieve any glyphicons in Bootstrap 2.3.2.

What am I missing ?

Thanks!

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="bootstrap.icon-large.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <a class="btn btn-small" href="#">
     <i class="icon-large icon-chat"></i>
 </a>
 <a class="btn btn-small" href="#">
     <i class="icon-large icon-phone"></i>
 </a>
 <img src="glyphicons.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap 2.3.2 uses a png sprite in order to call its icons.

if you'll look inside bootstraps css file you'll see that it's looking for this image under:

```
url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png")
```

whereas your image is on the same level as your css.

either change your png's location to this one (put it in the 'img' folder), or change the css file itself.

Mike.

Comment: Cant find any file bootstrap font file in v.2.3.2.

Comment: oh right, the old bootstrap, let me re-edit my answer

Comment: I have read this content from this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609569/missing-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-2-3-2" but it doesn't provide enough with information to solve this situation.